# AngularJS - get value of defined constants inside .constant

Tags: angularjs, constants

I have an angularJS .constant, which looks like this:

```
(function (angular, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('someModule')
    .constant('MyConstants', {
        VALUE_ONE: 12345,
        VALUE_TWO: VALUE_ONE // it says "VALUE_ONE is undefined"
    });
})(angular);
```

Note that when I write :
`VALUE_TWO: this.VALUE_ONE`, than my test is falling with msg:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.VALUE_ONE').

How can I get the value of VALUE_ONE inside MyConstants ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot do that, and I don't understand why you want that. If you want VALUE_TWO to depend on VALUE_ONE, then it is not a constant and you shouldn't try to include it in a constant.

If you want to have some set of constant values, including other values registered as CONSTANTS, you can define it as a property of an angular.js *Service*:

```
 angular.module('someModule') 
.factory('MyService', ['MyConstants', function(MyConstants) {
  return {
    compositeConstant: [MyConstants.VALUE_ONE, 1, 2, 3]; 
  }
}])
```

Comment: Maybe, for example, I will need constant list which contains that value, like this:
SOME_LIST: [VALUE_ONE, 1,3,4,5]

Comment: This still is NOT a constant, because it depends on VALUE_ONE. Just try to register the array as a service property

Comment: "register the array as a service property" - What do you mean ?